# How to show a read more link for p tag content when it exceeds a certain length with react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
{!post.isSearch && (
              <p className="text-sm">
                {post.postType == "post"
                  ? post.content
                  : truncate(post.content, { length: maxChars })}
              </p>
            )}
            {post.postType !== "post" && post.content.length > maxChars && (
              <NextLink href={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                <a className="text-ua-red text-left text-xs cursor-pointer 
                 hover:underline">
                  Read more...
                </a>
              </NextLink>
            )}
```

.Im getting data from firebase using next js. the data renders but  for some reason my code isnt working the  read more thing doesnt work

Comment: _"the read more thing doesnt work"_ - can you be more specific? What doesn't work? Does it not link to the the expected page? What happens instead?

Comment: Could you make a demo using https://stackblitz.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work ... heres the code

```
   {post.content.length > maxChars && (
              <NextLink href={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                <a className="text-ua-red text-left text-xs cursor-pointer hover:underline">
                  Read more...
                </a>
              </NextLink>
            )}
```

So I basicaly used css to shorten the string and a conditional to check string length to display read more